# selectNode() not working in IE8

Tags: tinymce, range

I need to select a node in tiny mce, I'm trying following code. It works in non-IE browsers, but on IE it gives error as - 
   **Error: Object doesn't support this property or method**

Code -

```
              rng = ed.selection.getRng();
              rng.selectNode(tn);
```

The second line causes the error. Is there any other IE compatible method for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is the different range object you get. In FF you get an object which offers you several functions like `selectNode()`. The IE range only presents you a textrange object which contains only properties.

The solution to this is easy:

```
// true is important here - causes getRng to return a DOM Range and not a text range (IE)
rng = ed.selection.getRng(true);
rng.selectNode(tn);
```

Comment: selectNode is not listed in methods of TextRange Object. I tested and found, though it is not generating any error, it is not working as desired. Thanks

Comment: that's what i just said in my answer. when you use getRng(true) you will receive a DOM range and NOT a text range! Which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I read about TextRange object and was able to do what I intended. I wanted to set my cursor inside a span. I could do it using TextRange object properties and methods as follows -

```
range.moveToElementText (node); //node is  the span in which I wanted to place my cursor
range.select ();
```

moveToElementText - Aligns the start and end points of the current TextRange object to the text content of the specified element. I added an nbsp; to the span and with the above code could replace it, by my caret.

Comment: why then you ask about the selectNode function and not about positioning of the caret?